# I receive error 'Unknown Server Tag' with Page.ParseControl on a custom server control, not asp control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor, custom-server-controls

I'm building a dynamic form using XML and XSLT. Anyway I'm using a custom asp.net control for [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), it's an HTML editor.

When I try to add the controls from the XSLT using `Page.ParseControl(<the-string-from-the-xslt-here>)`, I get a warning saying:

> Unknown server tag 'FCKeditor.CKEditor'

And of course, if I remove the control from the XSLT everything is working fine and all the regular asp.net controls like `TextBox` etc get rendered to the string just fine.

Does anyone know what I can do about it?

Comment: problems with CaPiTaLs in sentences? ;-)

Comment: This is not XSLT problem, as you could get the "<the-string-from-the-xslt-here>" from any source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a thread with a very similar question and the answer is:

> *To pass the register directive with
>   the string to the ParseControl
>   function.*

You can [read all about it here](http://forums.asp.net/p/376584/376584.aspx) or [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet.webcontrols/browse_frm/thread/1bb2ab396fd26b0b?hl=en&lr=&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&rnum=1&prev=/groups%3Fq%3DPage.ParseControl%2Btag%2Bprefix%26hl%3Den%26lr%3D%26ie%3DUTF-8%26oe%3DUTF-8%26selm%3D%2523lZ%2524jzRdCHA.1540%2540tkmsftngp10%26rnum%3D1).

Comment: It would really help if you follow-up on suggestions, like using CaPitals properly, that way we don't have to edit all your posts... :S

Comment: The suggestion is logical. But I assume the assembly containing CKEditor is already referenced, in which case it's both easier and makes your code more maintainable to add the reference in your web.config. That will remove that error forever.

Answer (score 0):

I can be mistaken, of course, but it's my understanding that [`FCKEditor.CKEditor`](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration) is a JavaScript element, not a server-side ASP.NET element. That's why you receive this error. Instead, you should instantiate the `CKEditor` on client-side (see the link for details).

Comment: you have a javascript object for FCKeditor thats correct but...
you also have an asp.net control they built.
which avcorse makes sense because you want to be able to refrence you ckeditor from the server side once a form was submited..

Comment: @guy schaller: *avcorse*? Can you give a link to that ASP.NET documentation of the CKEditor (or FCKEditor)? Once we see it, it'll be trivial to come up with a solution, in most cases.

Comment: i allready solved it you can read my solution here. its the second answear. it had nothing to do with ckeditor. just the way i sent a server control to the ParseControl function